# Reading Excel data with comma separated and carriage returns

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, c#-4.0

If my Sheet1 of my excel(.xls,.xlsx type files) is in this format and when i use my ReadExcel, i am able to bind this data as shown in the excel to the grid.

```
ID  Name     Code        

1   Mark     ABC001

2   Ryan     BBC001 

3   Will     CBC001
```

When there is data with comma separated (ID) and \n (carriage returns - Code - line 2), i don't get all the three rows, instead i get rows 1 and 3.

```
ID      Name      Code        

1       Mark      ABC001

2,5     Ryan,John BBC001 
                DBC001

3       Will      CBC001
```

Here is the method call:

```
private void ReadExcel(string filePath)
{
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));


            string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", filePath);
            using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConn))
                {
                    dbConn.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataRow row;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            row = table.NewRow();
                            row["ID"] = (string)reader[0];
                            row["Name"] = (string)reader[1];
                            row["Code"] = (string)reader[2];
                            table.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts on handling this, so that i can get data back like this?

```
ID      Name      Code        

1       Mark      ABC001

2       Ryan      BBC001

5     John      DBC001

3       Will      CBC001
```

Comment: Is this an .xlsx file or .txt / .csv??

Comment: table.Load(reader) in place of the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first change i did was to format the column type in excel to **text**(instead of general), then use split commands to create new rows, then it works.

```
  string[] Codes = reader["Code"].ToString().Trim().Split('\n');
  string[] IDs = reader["ID"].ToString().Trim().Split(',');



   for (int i = 0; i <= Codes.Count() - 1; i++)
   {
     //table.rows.add one by one..  
   }
```

Comment: Any solution that works is good. Although I still think that your file must be CSV disguised as XLS because if the file is XSL, the data contained in the cell and a comma shouldn't throw it off.